# Getting API values to dropdown from list page to edit page in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

First of all, I am using Material UI Library with react.js.

## List Page

when I click this method:

```
const handleEditClick = async (toolID) => {
    console.log("Tool ID:", toolID);
    const gettoolid = toolID;

    if (typeof gettoolid === "number") {
      
      const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await fetch(
            `API_LINK/${gettoolid}`
          );
          if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
          }
          const data = await response.json(); 
          setgetToolList(data); 
          console.log(data);

          // Store Api values in local 
          
          localStorage.setItem("ATplantID", data.plantID);

          navigate("/addtool");

        } catch (error) {
          // Handle errors here
          console.error("API Error:", error);
        }
      };
      // Call the fetchData function
      fetchData();
    }
  };
```

Its working well and I am getting values and stored in localstorage - ATplantID=2

## Add Page/Update Page

I am getting API for dropdown here:

`const { data: DD } = useApi(`${BASE_API_URL_Web}DD`);`

Based on this:

```
const [selectedPlant, setSelectedPlant] = useState(null);

return(
<Autocomplete
              disablePortal
              required
              id="plantid"
              size="small"
              options={DD.plantList}
              value={selectedPlant}
              onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                setSelectedPlant(newValue);
              }}
              getOptionLabel={(option) => option.plantName}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField {...params} label="Plant Area" variant="outlined" />
              )}
              renderOption={(props, option) => (
                <li {...props}>{option.plantName}</li>
              )}
            />
)
```

It is also working fine, but my question is how can I give that ATplantID=2 in that dropdown after that it have to show the value as second option in the dropdown?

I tried this:

```
const [selectedPlant, setSelectedPlant] = useState(ATplantID || null);
```

Did I do this really in correct way? That's what my biggest doubt.
Should I really use that localstorage?